# Save Compositing Nodes

Tags: compositing-nodes

Is it possible to save the nodes and node settings in the compositor tab for diffrent camera renders?

I would like to have different lighting for different renders within the same project, but I would like to be able to return later and just re-render the shot without changing the compositing nodes over again.[image]

Comment: Hello ! The compositor node tree is tied to the scene, not to cameras. So the only way would be to use "Linked Copy" scenes and use 1 different compositor node tree on each scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create different Node Group from your Compositing node setups.

When you change the Outliner view to Blend File, this node group will pop up there and you can right click it and make it an Asset.

Later on you then can grab the Node Group you want to use for Compositing from your Asset Browser.

Here is a Tutorial how to do this from Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hKZLlCZbDnI

Comment: I have the viewer and composite node inside the group but I don't see the backdrop image (composited image) anymore. Is it possible to turn it on?

Comment: I'm afraid I myself am fairly new to the Asset Browser and Compositing. So far I only used this technique in Geometry Nodes and Shader Nodes with more or less success, but I am not sure about the specific quirks with Compositing Nodes.

Comment: should I save the node groups separate from the file or they get saved automatically within the file?

Comment: To my understanding the standard is the Assets being saved in their respective file. I personally keep an Asset folder on my PC where I have GeometryNode.blend, Materials.blend, etc. In Preferences of Blender you can set your Asset Folder. This is where Blender then will look for Files containing Assets and list those Assets alltogether within the Asset Browser, no matter on which file you work.